# ¿error 'System.InvalidOperationException' conflicto al unir dos vistas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Tengo esta vista que necesita el modelo **Audit** pero la **masterPage** tiene `@Html.Partial("/Views/component/panelNavbar.cshtml")` hacen conflicto el modelo **Audit** con **ConfMaster** como solucionar esto?

**index Audit**

```
@model IEnumerable<CSHLPA.Models.Audit>

@{
Layout = "/Views/component/MasterPage.cshtml";
}
```

**PanelNavbar**

```
@using CSHLPA.Helpers
@model CSHLPA.Models.ConfMaster
<aside id="left-panel" class="left-panel">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-default">
     //mas codigo....
```

**Error Completo**

> Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException' en System.Web.Mvc.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario
>   Información adicional: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CSHLPA.Models.Audit]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CSHLPA.Models.ConfMaster'.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que en MasterPage.cshtml no utilizes un Partial View, sino un Child Action. Reemplaza @Html.Partial("/Views/component/panelNavbar.cshtml") por @Html.Action("ShowNavBar", "NavBar"). Crea un controller NavBarController con un action method ShowNavBar:

```
public class NavBarController : Controller {
    public ActionResult ShowNavBar() {
        return View("~/Views/Shared/panelNavbar.cshtml", new ConfMaster{ Nombre = "ConfMaster1" });
    }
}
```

Dado que el modelo de un master page es independiente de la vista donde es llamada, debe cargar su data desde un child Action.

Espero te ayude

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que cuando invocas un partial puedes pasarla un model como parametro

```
@Html.Partial("/Views/component/panelNavbar.cshtml", model)
```

Si analizas este articulo

[@Html.Partial Example - Render Partial View using @Html.Partial in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/HtmlPartial-Example---Render-Partial-View-using-HtmlPartial-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

veras como el model de la view principal tiene los datos para poder enviar a la view partial cuando usa

```
<td>@Html.Partial("Details", customer)</td>
```

Por lo general la master no deberia depender un model